# How to calculate the a 4 month cumulative value via mdx?

Tags: mdx

How to calculate cumulative value for last 3 months + the current month value, in an `mdx` query?

If I select May then it will give the cumulative value of this set {Feb, March, April, May}

Answer (score 1):

If you need to cover distinct counts as well as sums then `AGGREGATE` is the function to use but if distinct counts are not needed then you can simply use `SUM`.

If you have a month selected, or months `ON ROWS` then to return the month selected then something like the following should work:

```
[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember
```

To then go back 3 months you can add the `LAG` function:

```
[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember.LAG(3)
```

Now to get this range of months use the `:` operator:

```
[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember.LAG(3) 
: 
[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember
```

So this could now beused against a specific measure e.g. Revenue like this:

```
SUM(
  [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember.LAG(3) 
  : 
  [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember
 ,[Measures].[Revenue]
)
```

In a script this would be added to a `WITH` clause:

```
WITH    
MEMBER [Measures].[4MonthRevenue] AS
    SUM(
      [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember.LAG(3) 
      : 
      [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember
     ,[Measures].[Revenue]
    )  
SELECT 
    [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].MEMBERS
      ON ROWS,
    NON EMPTY
      [Measures].[4MonthRevenue]
        ON COLUMNS
FROM [YourCube];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a really helpful [article](http://blog.soft-prestidigitation.com/the-dynamic-members.html) for this case:

```
Aggregate(
    LastPeriods(
        3,
        StrToMember('[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[' + Format(Now(),'yyyyMM') + ']')
    ),
    [Measures].[YourNotCalulatedMeasure]        
)
```